# Selected value not working when passing back enum dictionary

Tags: c#, knockout.js, enums

I am creating a options list using knockout data-binding. Basically on my server side i have an enum

```
public enum CarType
{
    Saloon = 1,
    Hatch = 2,
    Convertable = 3,
    SUV = 4
}
```

This basically get created into a dictionary on the server side and is sent back to the client side.

So the above enum will return to the client side as an object with a key and value.

My viewmodel is like so:

```
this.carName= ko.observable();
this.carType = ko.observable();
```

My options binding is as below:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.carTypes, optionsText: 'value', optionsValue: 'key', value: carType"></select>
```

So basically when i press the edit button this view will get rendered correctly first time round. But if i cancel the edit page and re-open it then it selects the first element in the options list.

Not sure if i am doing anything wrong or if knockout behaves differently with dictionarys?

The car type object returned is an array of dictionary elements example below

```
[{key="1", value="Saloon"}, {key="2", value="Hatch"}  .......
```

Comment: Show the actual structure of `carTypes`. Also, why keeping both `carName` and `carType` when you can extract car-name from `carTypes`?

Comment: Can you please post the code that has the cancel and what the enum format is in javascript

Comment: Have added the object array that gets returned back from the server. I will need to send cancel and save code tomorrow.

Comment: Just to add I am using a dialog.js which comes packaged up with drundal so in the cancel it just uses the dialog.close which is part of the show function https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/src/plugins/js/dialog.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Do you wish to avoid the first item being selected? If so, take a look at the `optionsCaption` in the docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#parameters

> optionsCaption
>
> Sometimes, you might not want to select any particular option by
>   default. But a single-select drop-down list usually starts with some
>   item selected, so how can you avoid preselecting something? The usual
>   solution is to prefix the list of options with a special dummy option
>   that just reads “Select an item” or “Please choose an option” or
>   similar, and have that one selected by default.
>
> This easy to do: just add an additional parameter with name
>   optionsCaption, with its value being a string to display. For example:

```
<select data-bind='options: myOptions, optionsCaption: "Select an item...", value: myChosenValue'></select>
```

> KO will prefix the list of items with one that displays the text
>   “Select an item…” and has the value undefined. So, if myChosenValue
>   holds the value undefined (which observables do by default), then the
>   dummy option will be selected. If the optionsCaption parameter is an
>   observable, then the text of the initial item will update as the
>   observable’s value changes.